# How to get all items in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I've implemented one code to scan the wifi networks and display them in the list. After selecting one of the wifi networks from the list, I have added selected network in another activity in another ListView.

Now when I restart the app and again scan the wifi networks, I'm getting that network also which I have selected before and added in the list.
(In one activity I'm searching available wifi networks and in other activity I have added list of that selected networks)

So my question is that, how to hide that network which I have already added in list view?

This is my first activity, here i have displayed the added device in `listview`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });



        try
        {
            listView          = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.device_list);
            devicesNameEspNum = new ArrayList<>();
            devices           = new Devices();
            devicesList       = alldeviceList();

            for(int i=0; i<devicesList.size(); i++)
            {
                devices = devicesList.get(i);
                devicesNameEspNum.add(devices);
            }

            devicesAdapter = new DevicesAdapter(MainActivity.this,devicesNameEspNum);
            listView.setAdapter(devicesAdapter);
            devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent   = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Fourth.class);
                String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceNamList)).getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("DEVICE_ID",selected);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "****", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static  List<Devices> alldeviceList()
    {
        return new Select().from(Devices.class).execute();
    }
```

> This is my second activity to scan nearby wifi networks

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        list=getListView();
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(mainWifiObj != null)
        {
            mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        mainWifiObj.startScan();


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1000);

        }
        else
        {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        }


        // listening to single list item on click
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // selected item

                String ssid = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                connectToWifi(ssid);
                Toast.makeText(Second.this,"Wifi SSID : "+ssid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
```

> This is the class:

```
    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();

            System.out.println("Wifi Scan Result: "+wifiScanList);

            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

            for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++)
            {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }
            String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            int counter = 0;
            for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
                String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");

                filtered[counter] = temp[0].substring(5).trim();//+"\n" + temp[2].substring(12).trim()+"\n" +temp[3].substring(6).trim();//0->SSID, 2->Key Management 3-> Strength

                counter++;

            }

            System.out.println("Filtered :"+filtered);
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,R.id.label, filtered));


        }
    }
```

Comment: show your adapter's code please

Comment: store SSID of saved wifi.When you open next time run a loop in which check if any SSID matches already.then remove that index from array.After that display the final list

Comment: @AbdulAzeem but how to store the list of SSID, please share the code if pssible, thanks you in advance

Comment: Create two hashmaps. then store first scan data in one hashmap and when you restart the connection compare this new data in a hashmap with the first hashmap. Now you can hide the connection which is already existed in the first hashmap. @NehaGhadge

Answer (score 0):

What's about this ?

```
displayed.addAll(allItems.filter { !it.equals("abc") })
```